# Is there a way in angular currency filter to output price like 152€?

Tags: angularjs, filter, currency

is there any way I can output price like that? 152€.

If I use angular currency filter it will output like €152.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Divya is pretty good but incomplete because the angular currency filter does more than just add the symbol money after the amount. It also truncate to the correct number of digit after the dot, look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).
I think the best way is to right a new filter that internally use the angular filter :

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.filter('customCurrency',function($filter)
        {
            return function(amount, symbol, fractionSize){
                var result = $filter("currency")(amount, symbol, fractionSize);
                result = result.slice(symbol.length, result.length) + result.slice(0,symbol.length);
                return result;
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div>{{ 42.6732 | customCurrency : 'euro'}}</div>    
</body>
```

Comment: useful information! though we can generalize it by slicing it from  the length of the symbol
(useful in case if the symbol  has more than one character)

Comment: Thank you divya, I have taken your comment into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**In Controller**

`$scope.currency = 152;
$scope.currencySymbol = '$';`

**In Markup**

`{{currency| number}}{{currencySymbol}}`

Answer (score 0):

create a custom filter with the defined behaviour

```
.filter('customCurrency',function()
    {
        return function(amount){
            return amount+"$";
        }
    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s6vjjoLs/) is a Fiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/s6vjjoLs/